# start super small linux over pxe and run some commands

Tags: linux, pxe

I have a small script which runs a few commands on a client. until now i need to go with my usb drive to the pc, run my live image and then run the script. now i want to use pxe for this.

so the plan is: start a really really small kernel with the required ressources like network, disks, ... in it.
then start the script and reboot the machine.

so i can build a kernel, that should be no problem, but hwo can i start my script and stuff afterwards? i mean i could take a debian live or whatever and put the script into `/etc/rc.local` but thats way too much for that.
and i would need nfs for that, which i dont want to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is really simple:

create a kernel as you like, or just use one you just have lying around.
then create an initram like described here: http://blog.mybox.ro/2010/05/12/how-to-change-files-in-a-initrd-image/

inside the initram you spawn instead of a shell the script you need.